# Render is not a function updateContextConsumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, react-context

I have 3 components **(CompA, CompB, CompC)** I want to send data to from CompA to CompC but it is showing error **Render is not a function updateContextConsumer**. I am using functional components

```
import React,{ createContext } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CompA from './ContextApi/CompA';

const FirstName = createContext();

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <FirstName.Provider value={"JD"}>
        <CompA/>
      </FirstName.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
export {FirstName}; 


import React from 'react';
import CompB from './CompB';

const CompA = () =>{
    return(
        <CompB/>
    )
}

export default CompA;

import React from 'react';
import CompC from './CompC';

const CompB = () =>{
    return(
        <CompC/>
    )
}

export default CompB;

import React from 'react';
import {FirstName} from '../App';

const CompC = () =>{
    return(
        <>
            <FirstName.Consumer> {fname=>(<h1>{fname}</h1>) } </FirstName.Consumer>
        </>
    )
}

export default CompC;
```

Image of error is here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdjvW.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the spaces between the end of `<FirstName.Consumer>` and the `{` and the `}` and `</FirstName.Consumer>`. The following does not work with those spaces left in:

```js
const FirstName = React.createContext();

const CompA = () =>{
    return (
        <CompB/>
    )
};

const CompB = () =>{
    return (
        <CompC/>
    )
};

const CompC = () => {
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <FirstName.Consumer>{ (fname) => (<h1>{fname}</h1>) }</FirstName.Consumer>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FirstName.Provider value={"JD"}>
        <CompA/>
      </FirstName.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You could also put the `{ (fname) => (<h1>{fname}</h1>) }` part on a separate line like shown here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer